# Jmeter - How to output all the values extracted from JSON extractor

Tags: jmeter

I have json with dynamic range which is groving all the time.

```
{
    "payload": {
        "totalCount": 302,
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 1379,
                "date": "2021-04-08T17:06:03+02:00",
                "name": "Newcastle United Aston Villa",
                "externalId": "2",
                "mediaTag": null,
                "deleted": false,
                "originalId": null,
                "cancelled": false,
                "relatedEventsOrderIndex": []
            },
            {
                "id": 1380,
                "date": "2021-04-08T17:06:03+02:00",
                "name": "Arsenal Tottenham Hotspur",
                "externalId": "3",
                "mediaTag": null,
                "deleted": false,
                "originalId": null,
                "cancelled": false,
                "relatedEventsOrderIndex": []
            }
            
            
        ]
    },
    
    "errorCode": 0,
    "errorTimeStamp": null,
    "errorMessage": null,
    "hasError": false
}
```

I can extract all the values like

[image]

And if i use  as: ID1_1, ID1_2.......ID1_100 -> its working fine.

But, I want to output in the logger.
If I tried as:

```
def IDS = vars.getObject("ID1");

for (int i=0; i>IDS.length; i++) {
    
    log.warn("ID as: " + IDS + (i + 1) );
}
```

I got: Cannot get property 'length' on null object

How can I output all the ID, from dynamic JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have `ID1` variable, you have `ID1_1`, `ID1_2` .... and `ID1_matchNr` which holds the number of matches, you can see it yourself using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

You need to change your code as:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= vars.get('ID1_matchNr') as int; i++) {
    log.warn("ID as: " + vars.get("ID1_" + i));
}
```

in the above code `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this (pseudo code)

```
for (int i=0; i>IDS.length; i++) {
    
    log.warn("ID as: " + vars.get("ID1_" + i.toString() );
}
```

each of the ID1_1, ID1_2.......ID1_100 are variables. You can verify that using a `Debug Sampler`